# Rename file by removing url parameter in linux

Tags: linux, file, shell, file-rename, batch-rename

I downloaded some files using [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) and the files are in the following format:

```
test.zip?AWSAccesskeyId=XXXXXXX&Expires=00000000&Signature=ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Is there any way, to rename those files properly by removing the URL parameters. Also is there any way, to download such files, with proper name(without URL parameter) from `wget`.

I tried with `mmv` with the following command:

```
mmv "*.zip*" "#1.zip"
```

But I can't find any way to install `mmv`. I am using CentOS 6. So, please suggest any way, other than this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
for file in *.zip\?*; do mv "$file" "${file%%\?*}"; done
```

As far as I can tell, there's no option to `wget` telling it not to include the query string in the local filename. You can use the `-O` option to specify an explicit filename, and fix the driver script to remove the query string itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `ls *.zip?*`; do echo $i | cut -f 1 -d \? | xargs -n1 mv $i ; done
```

sorry to lazy to do checking for spaces in names right now. and unable to test. i don't have access to a bash based system at this moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `g++ >=4.9.2` then you can install [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) and do:

```
rnm -ns '/n/.zip' *.zip\?*
# /n/ expands to file name without extension.
```

Or

```
rnm -rs '/\.zip\?.*/.zip/' *.zip\?*
```